# BibDesk file .bib and iCloud

Tags: bibdesk

Since I work with LaTex on 4 different computers I thought I would put my bibdesk archive file (.bib) on my iCloud. Unfortunately, however, during compilation TexStudio does not find the file saying "I found no database files---while reading file mybibliography.bib". (The path to the .bib file is correct since I copied it directly from the menu in the Finder.)

If instead I move my archive file (.bib) bibdesk to a local folder on my computer everything goes back to working properly.

So I guess there is a problem with iCloud: can anyone tell me if this can be fixed?

Comment: For Macs or Linux machines you can create a local file that is a symlink to the file in the iCloud, in that case the OS handles the directory lookup instead of BibTeX.

Comment: Thank you Marjin: what does it mean to create a local file that is a symlink? On my iMac I have the default iCloud folder and I think it is a local folder that syncs with a cloud folder.

Comment: A symlink is more or less a shortcut to a file or folder with a different name and/or in a different location. This means that LaTeX and BibTeX are 'tricked' into thinking that your .bib file is in the local folder, and they can read it as if it was in that local folder, but actually it is somewhere else. This is a low level function of the operating system, which is independent of any cloud synchronization settings. See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/symlink-tutorial-in-linux-how-to-create-and-remove-a-symbolic-link/ for more information and examples.